# retrieve text inside tags in R

Tags: regex, r, tags

I'm trying to retrieve information from a text file that contains tags, e.g.:

```
<name> Joe </name>
```

The text file consists of multiple lines some with more of these tags (e.g. for height and weight) and some with just other text. I refer to the text file as "sheet" (see code below).

I would like to retrieve the text between the tags. I have come up with the following solution to do so:

```
m1 <- regexpr("<name> [a-zA-Z]+ </name>", sheet)
m2 <- regmatches(sheet,m1)
m3 <- gsub("<name> ", "", gsub(" </name>", "", m2))
m3
```

I have not worked with regular expressions before, but I was wondering whether I am not taking a detour with my 'regmatches'. It seems there should be a more direct way to retrieve text inside tags?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Your sample looks like HTML or XML; if it is, i.e. there is a formal structure around it, there might be better solutions, for example using the XML package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with one `gsub` call. Therefore you have create a group by surrounding your pattern by `(` and `)`. This group could be accessed with a number `\\1` (backreferences), e.g.:

```
sheet <- "<name>foobar</name>"
gsub(pattern="<name>([a-zA-Z]+)</name>", replacement="\\1", x=sheet)
# [1] "foobar"
```

But as @DieterMenne suggests you should try the *XML* package for HTML (it supports [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)):

```
library("XML")
doc <- xmlParse("<html><name>foobar</name></html>")
xpathSApply(doc, "//name", xmlValue)
# [1] "foobar"
```

Comment: Thanks sgibb and @DieterMenne. I wasn't aware of the XML package and will look into it. The file is no HTML, but it is structured indeed.